# add event to element after it remove itself and append itself again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to remove a button and alert() when i click it, then the function will append a 'same' button to a container div, after searching senior's legacy, 
i tried to use on()/live()/delegate()/ unfortunately they not work.

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="clicked()">Other one</button>
    <hr>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $("#container").append("<button id='btn_sub' onclick='clicked()'>Click Me!</button>");
    $("[id='btn_sub']").delegate(this,"click",function(){
        $("#container").empty();
        $("#container").append("<button id='btn_sub' onclick='clicked()'>Click Me!"+i+"</button>");
        i++;
    });//tried click/on click/live
});
function clicked(){
    alert(1);
}
</script>
```

Finally, in this example, the clicked function put out of $(document).ready() and the part of alert worked.

Is there any other method to do the same effect?
and why on()/live()/delegate()/ not work?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your jquery version?

Comment: jquery-3.3.1.js

Comment: Why do you need to remove the button and append it again? Can't just modify it?

Comment: .delegate is already deprecated

Comment: it does work the first time... new button element is added. but since the old button on which event handler was added is removed and not resubscribed to the new button element, count doesn't increment after 0. onclick="clicked()" works though.

Comment: I try to make a subPage function,Lol modify it is a good idea. Thanks

Comment: yes, deprecated.

Comment: how can I resubscribe to the new button in jquery?I tried to bind but failed, and it looks like a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off `$("[id='btn_sub']")` can be replaced with `$("#btn_sub")`, then it's actually better to use a class as you might have many buttons.

This is a working example as an illustration: https://codepen.io/antoniandre/pen/XoNNpO

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").on("click", '.btn_sub', function() {
        removeButton(this);
    });
});
function addButton() {
    $("#container").append("<button class='btn_sub'>Delete Me!</button>");
}
function removeButton(btn) {
    btn.remove();
}
```

> With the `on()` bound on the container, you actually make sure any matching button `.btn_sub` will get this event attached to them when they are created in the future.
>
> Regarding `live`, it does the same as `on` but is now deprecated so you can forget it. https://api.jquery.com/live/#live-events-handler

Comment: pleasure, let me know if something is unclear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use on function to attach event.http://api.jquery.com/on/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var i = 0;
 $("#container").append("<button id='btn_sub' onclick='clicked()'>Click Me!</button>");
 $("#container").on("click", "[id='btn_sub']", function(){
  $("#container").empty();
  $("#container").append("<button id='btn_sub' onclick='clicked()'>Click Me!" + i + "</button>");
  i++;
 });
});
function clicked() {
 alert(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="clicked()">Other one</button>
    <hr>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i = 0;
var btn = "<button id='btn_sub' onclick='clicked()'>Click Me!</button>";

($(function(){
    $("#container").append(btn);
    $("#container").on("click", '#btn_sub', function() {
        $("#container")
          .empty()
          .append($(btn).text($(btn).text() + " " + i++));
    });  
}));

function clicked() {
    alert(i);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <hr>
    <button onclick="clicked()">Other one</button>
    <hr>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```